# Transforming multiple JSX files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, reactjs, browserify

Is there a way to specify multiple source -> destination mappings when transforming jsx files to js files using browserify in grunt?

I have the following in Gruntfile.js that supports a single file transformation, but I was hoping to be able to specify a second mapping for another file. I know I can map based on wild card into a single combined destination file. However, that is not what I want since I don't want an "all or nothing" include of the react components on my various pages. Some of the components only apply to a few pages and should not be included everywhere.

```
browserify: {
            options: {
                transform: [ require('grunt-react').browserify ]
            },
            //How do I map a second file here without a wild card?
            client: {
                src: ['react_components/src/component1.jsx'],
                dest: 'react_components/build/component1.js'
            }
        }
```

Essentially what I hoped for is a way to provide an array of src-dest mappings in the same task in order to create multiple destination files:

```
client: [{
                src: ['react_components/src/component1.jsx'],
                dest: 'react_components/build/component1.js'
            }]
```

Something like the above json

Comment: I don't use grunt-browserify, but I'm assuming that the current output of the task is a single bundled file? If you want to output another bundle, you'll need a separate task. If you could provide an example of the output you'd like it might help make the question clearer.

Comment: Yes the output is a single bundle. Your suggestion to make separate tasks per bundle make sense. I guess my initial goal was to output multiple bundles per task, but that may not be supported...

Comment: It may be supported by grunt browserify, but anything is going to be running multiple browserify "bundles" behind the scenes. Browserify is all about a single destination. You can use [externa bundles](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#external-bundles) to build an app up through multiple bundles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for me, I do not use browserify, I use grunt-react and react-tools. grunt react allows user to define [**dynamic_mappings**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-react#overview), based on regular expressions, something like this:

```
//Gruntfile.js
grunt.initConfig({
    react: {
      dynamic_mappings: {
        files: [
          /* Controllers compiling. */
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: './app/scripts/controllers/src',
            src: ['**/*.jsx'],
            dest: './app/scripts/controllers/dest',
            ext: '.js'
          },
          /* ui-components compiling */
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: './app/scripts/ui-components/src',
            src: ['**/**.jsx'],
            dest: './app/scripts/ui-components/dest',
            ext: '.js'
          },
          /* JSX test compiling */
          {
            expand: true,
            cwd: './test/ui-components/src',
            src: ['**/**.jsx'],
            dest: './test/ui-components/dest',
                ext: '.test.js'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
});
```